# Fastlane Spaceship get team name with ConnectAPI

Tags: fastlane

I'm building a fastlane pipeline that I want to authenticate using only App Store Connect API Key.

I would like to get the developer team name.

With normal login I would write

```rb
Spaceship::Portal.login(...])
Spaceship::Portal.client.team_id = ...
team_info = Spaceship::Portal.client.team_information
team_info["name"]
```

Is there of getting the team name using only `Spaceship::ConnectAPI` ?

```rb
token = Spaceship::ConnectAPI::Token.create(
  key_id: key_id,
  issuer_id: issuer_id,
  filepath: File.absolute_path("#{file_name}")
)
Spaceship::ConnectAPI.token = token
```